# How to make a powershell replacement command more understandable

Tags: powershell, structure

So I already have a powershell script. However, when it replaces what its suppost to replace, it makes ONE line. This is really unorganized.

Current script

```
powershell -command "(Get-Content Contentlocation.html) -replace '</tr></table>', '<tr style=&quot;mso-yfti-irow:34&quot;><td valign=&quot;top&quot; style=&quot;width:180;padding-left:3.5pt; padding-right:3.5pt; padding-top:0cm; padding-bottom:0cm&quot; height=&quot;5&quot;><font size=&quot;4&quot;>%Date%</font></td><td valign=&quot;top&quot; style=&quot;width:500;padding-left:3.5pt; padding-right:3.5pt; padding-top:0cm; padding-bottom:0cm&quot; height=&quot;5&quot;><font size=&quot;4&quot;>%Location%</font></td><td valign=&quot;top&quot; style=&quot;width:523;padding-left:3.5pt; padding-right:3.5pt; padding-top:0cm; padding-bottom:0cm&quot; height=&quot;5&quot;><font size=&quot;4&quot;>%Amount%</font></td></tr></table>' | Set-Content contentlocation.html"
```

I would like it to look like this. (in the html document)

```
 <tr style="mso-yfti-irow:34">
  <td valign="top" style="width:180;padding-left:3.5pt; padding-right:3.5pt; padding-top:0cm; padding-bottom:0cm" height="5">
  <font size="4">DATE</font></td>
  <td valign="top" style="width:500;padding-left:3.5pt; padding-right:3.5pt; padding-top:0cm; padding-bottom:0cm" height="5">
  <font size="4">LOCATION</font></td>
  <td valign="top" style="width:523;padding-left:3.5pt; padding-right:3.5pt; padding-top:0cm; padding-bottom:0cm" height="5">
  <font size="4">AMOUNT</font></td>
 </tr>
```

And not like this

```
 <tr style="mso-yfti-irow:34"><td valign="top" style="width:180;padding-left:3.5pt; padding-right:3.5pt; padding-top:0cm; padding-bottom:0cm" height="5"><font size="4">DATE</font></td><td valign="top" style="width:500;padding-left:3.5pt; padding-right:3.5pt; padding-top:0cm; padding-bottom:0cm" height="5"><font size="4">LOCATION</font></td><td valign="top" style="width:523;padding-left:3.5pt; padding-right:3.5pt; padding-top:0cm; padding-bottom:0cm" height="5"><font size="4">AMOUNT</font></td>
```

Does anyone know if this is possible?
I hope I explained this well enough, if there was something you didn't understand then just write, then I'll try to clarify

Answer (score 2):

you are looking for

```
`r`n
`r = Carriage return
`n = Line feed
```

therefore

```
"</tr>`r`n</table>"

output
</tr>
</table>
```

You can also use [System.Environment]::NewLine

```
'</tr>'+ [System.Environment]::NewLine +'</table>'

output
</tr>
</table>
```

You can also use the newline in a variable

```
$n = [System.Environment]::NewLine
'</tr>'+ $n +'</table>'

output
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: If I the ` r` n into the string it inserts it as ` r` n and not as 2 lines

Comment: That is becuase u are using it in a single qoute ' `r`n ' which literally just displays what you typed. in double qoutes " ` r` n " is a new line.

Comment: So I put the  " ` r` n " with the " into my text where i want the enters, but there is no enters. Still just one big string...

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to make a whole script of it, you could pre-define a variable with your formated text.

```
$html = '</tr></table>'

$replace = '
<tr style="mso-yfti-irow:34">
  <td valign="top" style="width:180;padding-left:3.5pt; padding-right:3.5pt; padding-top:0cm; padding-bottom:0cm" height="5">
  <font size="4">DATE</font></td>
  <td valign="top" style="width:500;padding-left:3.5pt; padding-right:3.5pt; padding-top:0cm; padding-bottom:0cm" height="5">
  <font size="4">LOCATION</font></td>
  <td valign="top" style="width:523;padding-left:3.5pt; padding-right:3.5pt; padding-top:0cm; padding-bottom:0cm" height="5">
  <font size="4">AMOUNT</font></td>
</tr>'

$html -replace '</tr></table>', $replace
```

#### Edit

Here is a full working example:

```
$html = Get-Content 'Contentlocation.html'

$replace ='<tr style="mso-yfti-irow:34">
  <td valign="top" style="width:180;padding-left:3.5pt; padding-right:3.5pt; padding-top:0cm; padding-bottom:0cm" height="5">
  <font size="4">DATE</font></td>
  <td valign="top" style="width:500;padding-left:3.5pt; padding-right:3.5pt; padding-top:0cm; padding-bottom:0cm" height="5">
  <font size="4">LOCATION</font></td>
  <td valign="top" style="width:523;padding-left:3.5pt; padding-right:3.5pt; padding-top:0cm; padding-bottom:0cm" height="5">
  <font size="4">AMOUNT</font></td>
</tr>'

Set-Content -Path 'Contentlocation.html' -Value $html.Replace('</tr></table>', $replace)
```

Comment: Didn't work. It's not even making any output with this command

Comment: @error40 Create a `test.ps1` file and paste all the content from my comment inside it. Then run `powershell -File test.ps1` (assuming you are in the same directory). This is simply an example to illustrate how you could do it. It does not read from your HTML file, nor does it amend it.

Comment: So what you'r saying is that I can't use it? I have tried to read, and replace my html document. Using that script, however nothing happend. It didn't put any text into the html.